# How much actuation is used in videos for 550D?

Tags: canon-550d, video, shutter-actuations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does every frame of video (or live view) on a DSLR count as a shutter actuation?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/does-every-frame-of-video-or-live-view-on-a-dslr-count-as-a-shutter-actuation)

I am concerned about the amount of actuation used when taking a video on my Canon EOS 550D. I intend to use my 550D for heavy usage of video shooting.

How can I determine how much actuation is used for video taking?

This question may be relevant to [How can I get the actuation count for Canon EOS 550D/550D](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/how-can-i-get-the-shutter-actuation-count-for-canon-eos-500d-550d)?